# SQL Server: update table from xml string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

this is the first time I am working with an XML input in SQL.

I created the following procedure to insert all records from my XML string into my table which works well so far.

Can someone tell me how I have to change this so that it only inserts a record as new if the `itemID` (every record in my XML has this as well) does not yet exist in my table, column `itemID` - otherwise it should update the existing record with the new data from the XML.

I know how to use `IF NOT EXISTS` and `UPDATE` in general but am not sure how to realise this with an XML string as the input.

**My procedure (so far):**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[editor_UpdateQuestions]
    @xml xml
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO editor_Questions
        (
            categoryID,
            question,
            sortID,
            modDate,
            modBy       
        )
    SELECT  ParamValues.x1.value('categoryID[1]', 'int'),
            ParamValues.x1.value('question[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)'),
            ParamValues.x1.value('sortID[1]', 'int'),
            GETDATE(),
            ParamValues.x1.value('modBy[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM    @xml.nodes('/ranks/item') AS ParamValues(x1)

END
```

**Example XML input:**

```
<ranks>
    <item><itemID>25</itemID><categoryID>1</categoryID><question>some text</question><sortID>1</sortID><modBy>abc</modBy></item>
    <item><itemID>12</itemID><categoryID>1</categoryID><question>some text 2</question><sortID>2</sortID><modBy>abc</modBy></item>
    <item><itemID>9</itemID><categoryID>1</categoryID><question>some text 3</question><sortID>3</sortID><modBy>abc</modBy></item>
</ranks>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH new_Questions AS (
    SELECT  ParamValues.x1.value('itemID[1]'    , 'int'           ) AS itemID,
            ParamValues.x1.value('categoryID[1]', 'int'           ) AS categoryID,
            ParamValues.x1.value('question[1]'  , 'nvarchar(1000)') AS question,
            ParamValues.x1.value('sortID[1]'    , 'int'           ) AS sortID,
            GETDATE()                                               AS date,
            ParamValues.x1.value('modBy[1]'     , 'varchar(50)'   ) AS modBy
    FROM    @xml.nodes('/ranks/item') AS ParamValues(x1)
)
MERGE INTO editor_Questions AS old
USING new_Questions AS new
  ON (new.itemID = old.itemID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  old.categoryID = new.categoryID,
  old.question   = new.question  ,
  old.date       = new.date      ,
  old.sortID     = new.sortID    ,
  old.modBy      = new.modBy
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (    itemId,    categoryID,    question,    date,    sortID,    modBy)
  VALUES (new.itemId,new.categoryID,new.question,new.date,new.sortID,new.modBy);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply ! Can you give me some directions on how to use this ? Would this replace the whole query ?

Comment: Use it instead of your INSERT statement.  This MERGE will either INSERT or UPDATE each row, depending on whether it can match the itemID

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try that and get back in a few.

Comment: This works absolutely great - just had to remove itemID from the insert as this is auto-generated and changed date to modDate to be consistent with my column names. Thanks a lot for this - big help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge statement as below

```
MERGE editor_Questions AS Target
    USING (
    SELECT  ParamValues.x1.value('categoryID[1]', 'int') AS categoryID,
            ParamValues.x1.value('question[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS question,
            ParamValues.x1.value('sortID[1]', 'int') AS sortID,
            GETDATE() AS [Date],
            ParamValues.x1.value('modBy[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ModBy
    FROM    @xml.nodes('/ranks/item') AS ParamValues(x1)

    ) AS SOURCE
    ON Target.categoryID =SOURCE.categoryID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Target.question = Source.question,
            Target.sortID = Source.sortID,
            Target.modDate=Source.[Date],
            Target.ModBy = Source.ModBy
    WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN
    INSERT 
        (
            categoryID,
            question,
            sortID,
            modDate,
            modBy       
        )
    VALUES  (categoryID,question,sortID,[Date],ModBy);
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll check on this as well !

Comment: I replaced date with modDate as that's my column name and changed ModBy to modBy but it didnt update anything.

Comment: Update: I think you were just missing the categoryID in your first statements which is why this failed.

Comment: Figured it out. Your solutions works as well if you add the itemID to your select and change the source reference to itemID as this is the unique identifier.